# issue with mercury rails gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, blogs, mercury-editor

I was working on a blog app so I want to implemant mercury-rails gem into it, i tried and i got it the tool bar but i was unable to edit any content from my show page

even after everything i am using with the foundation front end framework

```
<p><span id="page_content class="mercury-region" data-type="editable">
<%=raw  @article.content %></span></p>

<h5><span   data-type="editable"><%= @article.title %></span></h5>
```

this is my gem file

```
# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'
gem 'zurb-foundation'
# See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', :platforms => :ruby

 gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end

gem 'jquery-rails'

# To use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~> 3.0.0'

# To use Jbuilder templates for JSON
# gem 'jbuilder'

# Use unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Deploy with Capistrano
# gem 'capistrano'

# To use debugger
# gem 'debugger'
gem 'simple_form'
gem 'friendly_id'
gem 'devise'
gem "rmagick"
gem "carrierwave"
gem "mercury-rails"
```

Answer (score 4):

By the looks of things you've followed the old railscast. The mercury-rails projects updates quite frequently.

The problem lies in your attributes on the span tag. You can safely remove the `class="mercury-region"`

You will also need to change `data-type="editable"` to `data-mercury="full"`.

See the different edit types (defined in the `data-mercury` attribute) on the github page: https://github.com/jejacks0n/mercury#region-types

I hope that helps!

Comment: but this still was unable to save

Comment: You were asking about why you cannot edit elements. Did my response answer that? If so please accept it :) In regards to saving with mercury you'll need to customise it's save url and make sure you save the data correctly. There are many sources on the internet for such. Look for "Mercury editor rails saving" or something similar.